# Solr not including the end date in search date range

Tags: apache, search, solr, lucene

I have a Solr query which searches between dates and in my case, i'm searching between October 22 and October 26, want both dates to be included in the search. When I execute my query which contains

```
lastupdateddate:[2018-10-22 TO 2018-10-26])
```

I see results from 10/22 but not 10/26. When I change the end date to 10/27, I now see results from 10/26 so there is definitely data available for 10/26. I am not sure if there is a setting somewhere which is not bringing back data and including end date.

Comment: Could you past definition of the fieldType of lastupdateddate?

Comment: What is the actual value stored? If this is a date field, and you're not giving a timestamp, `00:00:00` will be used - and if your documents actually have timestamps after 00:00, they will not be included.

Comment: This is from my schema.xml   <field name="lastupdateddate" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
It is a string and the left (start/first) value is doing the search as expected but the right (end/last) value is not.

Comment: Could you show example of the input document? Cause for me, the same field type and range query is working just fine

Comment: You mean the schema.xml file right? Here is how it's defined <field name="lastupdateddate" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />